# How to show ripple effect at only at specify part of the widget during onTap

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, widget, ripple-effect

let's say I have a column widget inside I have two widget one contains a image and second some text, I want to show ripple effect **ONLY** on the image while the whole column is tapped.

I tried making a custom animation with opacity but it didn't work as excepted.

Comment: if you know the image height, you can try with  tap position from GuestureDetecture .

Comment: I know the image height but what about the the ripple effect then? As far as I know GuestureDetecture doesn't have it.

Comment: Well, I've failed. btw are you also using or ok to have fixed Sized on Text widget, if so then I am might try with Stack

Comment: well if it can't be helped i don't mind fixed sized on text widget